How do i program a custom dnd adventure bot with discord.py
I'm trying to make Discord bot that subtracts a number from a set value.
And edit the message as so:
p1hp = 20
p2hp = 17
p3hp = 16 

pphp = str(input("Who is getting hit ?"))
dmg = int(input("How much damage did you take?"))

if pphp == 'p1':
    everyplayerhealth = p1hp
elif pphp == 'p2':
    everyplayerhealth = p2hp
elif pphp == 'p3':
    everyplayerhealth = p3hp

dmgtakenPhp = (everyplayerhealth) - (dmg)

if dmgtakenPhp == 0:
    print("You are dead!")
else:
    print("You were at",everyplayerhealth,"Health, you took",dmg,"Damage, you now have",dmgtakenPhp,"Health")

I want to use the code I made with a discord bot that edits a discord message so, I can make a health system for the dnd I"m making.
I tried learning how to make one, but it was all confusing to me.

I know this isn't exactly a question but giving newbies some OOP action might be useful and helpful for op.
So here you go:
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all() #Can be changed for more specific intents.
bot = commands.Bot(intents=intents,command_prefix="!!")

class Player():
    def __init__(self,player_number,health=100): #Initialize player with given health and ordinal
        self.player_number = player_number
        self.health = health
        self.is_dead = False
        
    def hit(self,dmg): #Make player take damage
        self.health -= dmg
        self.check_death() #check death after hit
        
    def check_death(self):
        if self.health<=0:
            self.is_dead = True
            
#Create 3 players with different healths.
Players = [] #List of players
Players.append(Player(1,health=20)) #P1
Players.append(Player(2,health=17)) #P2
Players.append(Player(3,health=16)) #P3

@bot.event
async def on_ready(): #It's good practice to have on_ready function
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user.name}") #Successfully loaded the bot

@bot.command()
async def hit_player(ctx,player_number,dmg):
    player = Players[int(player_number)-1] #Get the player from player number
    dmg = int(dmg)
    player.hit(dmg)
    
    if player.is_dead:
        await ctx.send(f"Player{player.player_number} has died.")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"Player{player.player_number} took {dmg}. You now have {player.health} health.")
    
bot.run("YourBotToken")

You can now say:

!!hit 2 10

to hit the second player with 10 damage.
